# Is it still advisable to use iFrame to show another page within an HTML? If not, is there an alternative?

Tags: html, iframe

What we plan to do is to display a particular page from another site on our webpage (not really a whole page but it's more like a box within a page with job listings on it). However, I heard iFrame is no longer advisable to use.

Is it still okay in this instance (only 1 page and 1 iFrame)? Or are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

@Breezer is right in the fact that you want to use iframes as little as possible for as little of your content as possible(for SEO purposes and the fact you aren't hosting the content, so it could go down at anytime). Aside from this, I doubt the page you are trying to display is being rendered in a way that you want to display on your site anyways. Being a third party site you can use something like curl (server side) to screen scrape the data and parse out what you'd like to display on your site. Or, if you're looking for a client side alternative, you can use YQL to grab that third party information and then render as you may.

Here's a great tutorial on YQL, and doing exactly what you want, from @Nettuts (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/)

Hope that gives you some options.

Answer (score 0):

well it's fine using iframes to show another external webbpage, what's bad is building an entire website around a iframe because that will be hard to search engines to interrupt what your website is about therefore rank it lower in the search results

Comment: Not to mention the fun that a linked-to site can have with the content of your page if you simply iframe their site into your own without their permission.

Comment: and yeah and then there is that

Comment: did you mean ['infer'](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=infer) (rather than ['interrupt'](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=interrupt))?